# Flexbox issues in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, flexbox

My issue is when I'm displaying the Department Cards in the row they are displaying in a column instead of a row. I already tried to change it with CSS but the issue persists. Can you spot what the issue is here?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import DepartmentCards from '../Cards/departmentCards';
import FormacaoCards from '../Cards/formacaoCards';
import AddCollectionCard from '../Cards/addColeectionCard';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


function Formacao() {

  const [selectedDepartment, setSelectedDepartment] = useState(null);

  function handleDepartmentClick(departmentTitle, departmentImage) {
    setSelectedDepartment({ title: departmentTitle, image: departmentImage });
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-0">
      <Row lg="12" md="12" style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: "22vh", paddingLeft: "100px", paddingRight: "100px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", marginTop: "30px", marginBottom: "30px"}}>
        <DepartmentCards
          departmentTitle={'IT'}
          departmentImage={
            'https://leverageedublog.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/23174648/B-Tech-Degree.jpg'
          }
          handleDepartmentClick={handleDepartmentClick}
        />

        <DepartmentCards
          departmentTitle={'MKT'}
          departmentImage={
            'https://www.bschool.cuhk.edu.hk/wp-content/uploads/CUHK_MKT_001.jpg'
          }
          handleDepartmentClick={handleDepartmentClick}
        />

        <DepartmentCards
          departmentTitle={'RH'}
          departmentImage={
            'https://blog.unicep.edu.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/gestao-pessoas-scaled-1-scaled.jpg'
          }
          handleDepartmentClick={handleDepartmentClick}
        />

        <DepartmentCards
          departmentTitle={'FIN'}
          departmentImage={
            'https://investidorsardinha.r7.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/planejamento-financeiro-o-que-e-pra-que-serve-e-como-fazer-3-1200x720.jpg'
          }
          handleDepartmentClick={handleDepartmentClick}
        />
      </Row>
      <Row lg="12" md="12" style={{ borderTop: '2px solid #e0e0e0', paddingTop: '30px', paddingLeft: '130px', paddingRight: '100px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: selectedDepartment ? 'space-evenly' : 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: '30px' }}>      
        {selectedDepartment ? ( 
          <>
          <AddCollectionCard />
          <FormacaoCards
              formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
              formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          <FormacaoCards
            formacaoTitle={selectedDepartment.title}
            formacaoThumbnail={selectedDepartment.image}
          />
          </> )
          :
          <AddCollectionCard /> }
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Formacao;
```

**DepartmentCards:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardActions from '@mui/material/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ButtonBase from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase';


export default function DepartmentCards({departmentTitle, departmentImage, handleDepartmentClick}) {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => handleDepartmentClick(departmentTitle, departmentImage)}>
        <Card sx={{ width: 275, zIndex: -10 }}>
            <CardContent
                style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${departmentImage})`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover', // Add this line
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', // Optional: To prevent repeating
                minHeight: 100, // Adjust the total height accordingly
                }}
            >

            </CardContent>
            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 30, color: 'black', margin: "10px" }} gutterBottom>
                {departmentTitle}
            </Typography>
        </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the preview of the code:
[image: This is the preview of the code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the container (parent) that holds the DepartmentCards has a flexbox display with a row direction:

.container {display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;}